# Install Numpy in VirtualEnv on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv, easy-install

How can I install numpy in virtualenv...

easy_install numpy is throwing error.. I can not use the binary installer because this would install numpy in the python main installation and not in virtualenv..

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114115/windows-virtualenv-pip-numpy-problems-when-installing-numpy?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Another (not so great) solution is to get the installer, install it into your default Python directory, then copy it over to your virtualenv manually.

**Long version**

1. Go here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
2. Install it.
3. Find it in your python installation (probably at C:\Python27\Lib\site_packages\numpy, or similar
4. Copy the numpy directory over to $virtual_env\Lib\sites_packages\numpy.

Worked for me, but it's not elegant. I think there are also exe installers on numpy's site, but I find it's easier to just go to the one above when I need things than to poke around on various other sites.

Comment: Worked. not elegent though...  pip does not see the numpy install so it is not listed in the pip freeze

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use easy_install directly for fairly technical reasons I would rather not get into. There is a solution, albeit not optimal: once in the virtual environment, go into numpy sources, and run:

```
python setupegg.py install
```

The key point is using setupegg.py instead of setup.py.

Comment: Hrm, doesn't work for me. Says: `No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils. error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: Do you have visual studio installed ?

Comment: Nope...that a dependency for numpy on Windows?

Comment: you need a C compiler, yes. Either visual studio, or mingw32 (in which case you need to call something like seutpegg build_ext -c mingw32). But really, you should just install numpy from binaries.